# How to get Magento Order data from Observer

Tags: php, oop, magento, events, event-handling

Ok, Ive searched all over the web and nothing worked. The results were very inconsistent. Let me first show you what I have here. It will create an export file in the end but unable to obtain order data and object.

```
class Packagename_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function exportFeed (Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

        $ordered_items = $order->getAllItems();
```

and in config.xml

```
<global>
  <events>
        <sales_order_place_after>
            <observers>
                <packagename_modulename_order_observer>
                    <class>Packagename_Modulename_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>exportFeed</method>
                </packagename_modulename_order_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_order_place_after>
    </events>
</global>
```

Now, Ive seen people use without Varien_Event_Observer like that,

```
public function exportFeed ($observer)
```

Ive also tried without getEvent()

```
$order = $observer->getOrder();
```

and something different in config.xml, with and without singleton

```
<type>singleton</type>
<class>packagename_modulename/observer</class>
```

All I want to do is export an inventory feed of that particular item ordered when an order is placed via Magento.

Comment: So what is the problem? have you your order in such way `$observer->getEvent()->getOrder()`?

Comment: The problem is that I could not get the order object which containing the ordered item and its QTY and other attributes. Yes, I've tried $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();

Comment: -> getOrder is very big for a log output. Happens to me too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

In config.xml

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <Packagename_Modulename>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </Packagename_Modulename>
  </modules>
  ....
  <global>
   <models>
        <packagename_modulename>
            <class>Packagename_Modulename_Model</class>
        </packagename_modulename>
   </models>
   <events>
      <sales_order_place_after>
         <observers>
            <packagename_modulename_order_observer>
                <type>singleton</type>
                <class>modulename/observer</class>
                <method>exportFeed</method>
            </packagename_modulename_order_observer>
         </observers>
      </sales_order_place_after>
```

In Observer.php

```
class Packagename_Modulename_Model_Observer 
{
   public function exportFeed($event)
    {
        $order = $event->getOrder();
        foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $item){
           $item->getQtyOrdered() // Number of item ordered
           //$item->getQtyShipped()  
           //$item->getQtyInvoiced()

           $optionArray = $item->getProductOptions()
           // Todo : check to see if set and is array $optionArray['options']
           foreach($optionArray['options'] as $option){
               // Mage::log($option)
               //echo $option['label']
               //$option['value']
           }
        }
```

Comment: <models><packagename_modulename>... So in this case you need to change `<class>modulename/observer</class>` into `<class>packagename_modulename/observer</class>`